# How to check if it's nighttime in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've wrote a function which returns true/false depending on whether it's nighttime or not.

```
isNight() {
    var date = new Date();
    return (date.getHours() > 22 && date.getHours() < 6);
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Can somebody help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: how can a number be greater than 22 and smaller than 6 at the same time? You want `||`, not `&&`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I want to work between 10pm and 6am.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a concept of the fact that a day ends after hour 23, so either it's before 6 OR it's after 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where missing the `function` in front of your function name, that throws error number one.

Secondly, you've got a logical error. A number can't be greater than 22 and lower than 6 at the same time. Check if the number is greater than 22 **or** lower than 6.

```js
function isNight() {
  var date = new Date();
  return (date.getHours() > 22 || date.getHours() < 6);
}
console.log(isNight());
```

Comment: it`s class method (es6 feature), works for me. thanks!

Comment: @РомаБойко Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `||` instead of `&&`

```
function isNight() {
    var date = new Date();
    return (date.getHours() > 22 || date.getHours() < 6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNight() {
    var date = new Date();
    return (date.getHours() > 22 || date.getHours() < 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution for this.

```
function isNight() {
    var hours = new Date().getHours()
    var isNightTime = hours < 6 || hours > 22
    return isNightTime;
}
```